# Заменить цвет в картинке на прозрачный

Tags: php, изображения

Как заменить определенный цвет в картинке на прозрачный?

**Обновление**

Да, средствами php. Есть 2 картинки. Одна обычная, вторая - с маской (ромб, центр прозрачный). В тоге после склеивания [получается](http://take.ms/juhrK). Как удалить белый цвет и сделать его прозрачным?

Comment: Вы это средствами php делать собрались?

Comment: Так рубашка тоже белая. И она тоже станет прозрачной.

Comment: Да, станет прозрачной) Цвет может быть черный, синий... Но суть не в этом, а в том, как место определенного цвета заменить на прозрачный )